# Add array values from textboxes and display in a label

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HTVT.jpg) <<< my interface

I am working on something for my exam next week.

I must use Visual Basic. I am supposed to create an array with an integer and string. Integer = distance String = name. there will be 2 textboxes, 2 labels and 2 buttons.

> txtname.text, txtdistance.text, lblname, lbldistance, btninputdata and btnshowcontent

btninputdata should be disabled after filling the 30 arrays and making btnshowcontent to be visible and show all the 30 values (inserted values via textboxes) in lblname and lbldistance.

Whereas they both need to be inserted via a textbox store into the array and then using a btnshowcontent the stored array should be displayed on separate labels of name and distance.

My codes:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim ara(29) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub btninputdata_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btninputdata.Click

    If txtname.Text <> "" Then
        For h As Integer = 0 To 29
            If ara(h) = "" Then
                ara(h) = txtname.Text
                txtname.Clear()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Label1.Text = ara.ToString()


        Next
        MsgBox("arry full")
        btninputdata.Visible = False
        btnshowcontent.Visible = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnshowcontent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnshowcontent.Click
    'ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    'ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ara)
    ''Label1.Text &= ara(I) & ""

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Show us some code, what you try so far. For array you can use `List(Of *yourCustomClass*)` and fill it with every input and so on.

Comment: please read my post again i added my codes there. thank you

Comment: Label1.Text = ara.ToString() should be either:

    Label1.Text = ara(h).ToString() - display only the recently inserted record. 
    Label1.Text = String.Join(",", ara) - Display the entire array, separated by commas

Comment: Sir Nathan, Thank you for your help. It worked out!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to start with something like this.  Not sure how you're really trying to display everything, though.  You'd probably want to do validation on the distance field also.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Ara As New List(Of MyGroup)

Private Sub btninputdata_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btninputdata.Click
    If txtName.Text.Trim() <> String.Empty Then
        Ara.Add(New MyGroup With {.Name = txtName.Text, .Distance = txtDistance.Text})

        If Ara.Count >= 30 Then
            'Show/Hide buttons

        End If

    End If
End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyGroup
    Public Name As String
    Public Distance As Decimal
End Class
```

If you truly must use an array you can do something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Ara(29) As MyGroup

Private Sub btninputdata_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btninputdata.Click
    If txtName.Text.Trim() <> String.Empty Then

        Dim EmptyLocation = Array.FindIndex(Ara, Function(x) x Is Nothing)

        If EmptyLocation > -1 Then
            Ara(EmptyLocation) = New MyGroup With {.Name = txtName.Text, .Distance = txtDistance.Text}
            Return
        End If

        'Show/Hide buttons
        'Display the results however.

    End If
End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyGroup
    Public Name As String
    Public Distance As Decimal
End Class
```

Comment: thank you for your help,sir. actually i want to display the array as in a list view and when btnshowcontent is clicked all the stored arrays should be shown. :)